# wicket_pdf convert HTML to PDF without displaying HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wicked-pdf

If I render html page, I can get its content and use it to create PDF, like so:

```
content = params[:html]
```

But what if I don't want to display the HTML of the PDF I'm exporting? I tried different variations of this:

```
content = render_to_string(
    partial: 'some_partial.html.erb', locals: @some_var
)

respond_to do |format|
    format.pdf do
        render pdf: 'some_pdf', locals: { content: content },
                                template: 'some_template.pdf.erb',
                                disable_javascript: true
    end
end
```

But I just get errors, which leads me to believe that I'm coping this the wrong way...

Comment: So, you want to just download the PDF without generating it from HTML ?

Answer (score 0):

What you could is

Create a file with a unique name -

`unique_filename = Rails.root.join('public/', "#{SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64}.pdf").to_s`

Use render_to_string to create the PDF -

```
pdf_file = render_to_string :pdf => unique_filename, 
                            :template  => 'some_template.pdf.erb',
                            :save_to_file => '#{unique_filename}'
                            :save_only => true
```

Save it to the file

```
File.open(unique_filename, 'wb') do |file|
  file << pdf_file
end
```